# ASP.net newline is constante

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, connection

i have been trying to **insert data** to my database with ASP.net

the code with which i have been trying to insert data:

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // connection
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=YANNICK\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Klas; Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    // values de  insert statement toewijzen
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kijkerv", txtGastV.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kijkerT_V", txtGastT_V.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KijkerA", txtGastA.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KijkerEmail", txtEmail.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kijkershow", txtShowId.integer;

    // insert statement
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblKijker (Kijkerv, KijkerT_V, KijkerA, ShowId, Email) VALUES (@kijkerv, 
    @kijkerT_V, @KijerA, @KijkerEmail,  @Kijkershow);";

    try {
        connection.open();
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }



}
```

the error message is: newline in constant
what does this error mean/ how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found my own problem:

i had forgotten to add the libraries to set up a connction to my sql into my file

the code would look like this:

```
// library to work in DATABASES
using System.Data;

// library especially for SQL
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query string `CommandText` is in two lines. Remove the newline or put `@` before your query string like this :

```
command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tblKijker (Kijkerv, KijkerT_V, KijkerA, ShowId, Email) VALUES (@kijkerv, 
    @kijkerT_V, @KijerA, @KijkerEmail,  @Kijkershow);"
```